# How to add a route for a specific subnet?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have a Linux computer and an `eth0` interface with 2 IPs:

```
ip : 10.10.1.1
mask : 255.128.0.0
gw : 0.0.0.0

ip : 10.22.32.1
mask : 255.255.255.0
gw : 10.22.32.254
```

I would like to add a specific gateway for network 10.22.0.0/16, so this is what I did:

```
route add -net 10.22.0.0/16 gw 10.22.32.254 dev eth0
```

This doesn't work, and I can't reach machines on 10.10.0.0 anymore. Here is the routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.128.0.0     U     1      0        0 eth0
10.22.0.0       10.22.32.254    255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.22.32.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
```

Does it fail because 10.22.0.0/16 is a subpart of 10.10.0.0/9?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means directly connected, is 10.10.0.0 behind a router?

Comment: Yes, the 10.10.0.0 network is directly reachable (no routing needed)

Comment: Route will tend to chose the closest match, so only 10.22.0.0 - 10.22.255.255 will be routed towards 10.22.32.254. Otherwise it would chose 0.0.0.0. I'd check if `1.` the machines in 10.10.0.0 have any routes, and `2.` that 10.22.32.254 is configured correctly to route.

Comment: There's no doubt that 10.22.32.254 is correctly configured and machines in 10.10.0.0 don't have routes. I also thought that it took the closest match, but it doesn't seem to do so :(

Comment: When did the problem start? I'm wondering if the issue isn't due to the fact that the `10.22` IP falls into the `10.10` network, so when it sends traffic, it will fall back to originating from `10.10.1.1` .

Comment: As the later linux kernels all decide route based on the most specific destination address, your best bet here is to try and traceroute, and see how far you get a response. My first instinct here is to think the reverse route is incorrect, check your routing on the gateway.

Comment: I already tried traceroute, but can't even reach the first hop, and the routing gw is correct as everything works fine if I have only one IP address and the gw configured as default gw :(

Comment: Then it's an issue with originating IP, try setting up a policy route for 10.22.0.0 .

Answer (score 1):

The computer uses the destination IP address to decide which route to choose. Your command says that for a destination IP address that matches `10.22.0.0/16`, you should send it directly to `10.22.32.254` for further routing. Based on your routing table, anything that doesn't match `10.x` or `169.x` will be placed directly on the line, not passed to the router machine.

This looks backwards. If you can reach `10.22.332.254` for sending these packets, you probably already have an interface that matches `10.22.0.0/16` which means those packets could go straight on the line without being passed to a gateway/router. What you probably want is anything that matches `10.22.x.x` goes directly on the line, while anything else (the internet, for example) gets passed to the router at `10.22.32.254`:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.22.32.254    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
10.22.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 1):

The network layout has several issues:

1. As Stache has pointed out the supposed router for 10.22.0.0/16 needs to have a reachable interface in the subnet "10.10.1.1/9" (see below). As it is, it can only be reached from inside the same subnet which doesn't make sense.
2. The "10.10.1.1/9" subnet is actually the 10.0.0.0/9 subnet which *contains the 10.22.0.0/16 subnet*, which is probably where all the confusion comes from.
3. The very first information you provide is that you use the 10.22.32.0/**24** subnet - you'll need to sort that out as well. You can supernet and subnet the routes but you need to make sure that it fits together.

You'll need to sort out subnet addresses and masks. If you use 10.10.0.0/**16** you can use 10.22.0.0/16 as a distinct subnet but you'll need a router with an interface *within each subnet*.